# Which membership plugin enables users to enter html links in blogs and on their profile page?

Tags: plugins, html, profiles, membership, community

I would like to make a community that enables users to have a nice profile page that enables them to put html links. I tried several plugins as Buddypress, ultimate member, profile grid etc. But they all do not allow me to put html code on the profile page of a user. Any ideas how I could manage this?
Thanks!

Comment: the capabilities of publishing HTML bring the capability to create XSS code. if you agree that, you have to find which hooks will allow HTMl in theses plugins. another way is to create new fields where user put links and then you generate HTML link based of theses fields.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Do you have any idea which plugin I need such the they can put a link such that it will become a html link on their profile? I think it is better to not do the first option that you mentioned..